# How to make a query with a must filter on nested fields from different hierarchies

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following object in my index:

```
{
    "user" : {
        "info" : {
            "fname" : "John",
            "lname" : "Stark"
        },
        "settings" : {
            "hide_menu" : true,
            "time_offset" : 3
        }
    },
    "views" : [
    ]
}
```

This is the mapping:

```
{
    "dynamic" : "false",
    "properties" : {
        "user" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "dynamic" : "false",
            "properties" : {
                "info" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "dynamic" : "false",
                    "properties" : {
                        "fname" : {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "index" : "not_analyzed"
                        },
                        "lname" : {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "index" : "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "settings" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "dynamic" : "false",
                    "properties" : {
                        "hide_menu" : {
                            "type" : "boolean"
                        },
                        "time_offset" : {
                            "type" : "long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'd like to create a filter to find all the users whose first name is John and have time_offset=3
So I need to build a must filter, but the problem is that these 2 fields are nested on different hierarchies: user.info and user.settings

How can I make a must filter (AND) with both of them?

Comment: Did u create the mapping for this document type. can u share that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply refer the fields with the dot notation.

```
"filter":{
     "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "user.info.fname": [
                            "John"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "user.settings.time_offset": [
                            3
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Updated Query as per mapping provided

```
{
    "filter": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "user",
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "user.info",
                                "filter": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "user.info.fname": [
                                            "John"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "user.settings",
                                "filter": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "user.settings.time_offset": [
                                            3
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. If it was so simple, then what is the purpose nested filters? I have elastic search 1.3.2

Comment: Please provide the full mapping 'coz it depends on the mapping which type of query can be used. The query I have provided is for type object. Have updated for nested type. Anyway do provide the full mapping detail

Comment: I've edited my question with the mapping. The type is nested and not object. That's because I make nested aggregations on the fields. (changing the mappings is not an option, I hope that there is a solution to my problem). thanks.

Comment: @Edi: i have edited the query as per the mapping you have provided